# Using the Lemma for Uniqueness of Measures

Tags: measure-theory

The Lemma: Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a $\sigma$-finite Measure Space. Let $\epsilon \subset \Sigma$ be a generator of $\Sigma$ which is closed unter intersections. Let $E_1,E_2,... \in \epsilon$ with $\cup_{i\in \mathbb{N}}=\Omega$ and $\mu(E_i)< \infty$. Then every $\mu$ is Unique by the Values $\mu(E), \ E\in\epsilon$.

The Exercise i did was the following:

- Let $(\Omega, \Sigma)$ be a measurable space and ${B}$ an Algebra with $\sigma(B)=\Sigma$. So $B$ generates $\Sigma$.
- Let $f: \Omega \to \Omega$ be a function with $f^{-1}(A) \in \Sigma$, $\forall A \in \Sigma$. Let $\mu$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure, that is $f$-invariant in $B$, so $\mu(f^{-1}(B_k))=\mu(B_k)$,   $\forall B_k \in B$.

Show, that the inviant property hold for every $A \in \Sigma$.

Solution:
Since $B$ is an Algebra, it is closed under intersections. It also generates $\Sigma$. So with Lemma above it follows, that $\mu(f^{-1}(A))=\mu(A)$, $\forall A \in \Sigma$.

**My Question**:
How do i show, that there is a $E_1,E_2...\in B$ with $\bigcup E_i=\Omega$. Since this is necessary for Measures, but not for Probability-Measures.
Otherwise the Solution is wrong i think.

Comment: They probably forgot to mention that the space is $\sigma$-finite (like the measure is)

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks!